using strategy.exit() vs strategy.close()
Having trouble changing strategy.close into strategy.exit functions...
Version 1: (Using strategy.close)
if strategy.position_size > 0
    if (condition_1) and low <= UP1
        strategy.close('Long')
        alert('123456789,closelong,EURUSD', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

Version 2: (Using strategy.exit)
if strategy.position_size > 0
    if (condition_1)
        strategy.exit('EXIT', from_entry='Long', stop=UP1)
        if low <= UP1
            alert('123456789,closelong,EURUSD', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

How would you make these two logically equivalent? They are behaving differently on the charts.
